# ReactJS - sharing an array of data among components without props

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So I'm building a simple app that uses similar data in couple of components.

To put it all in state and pass through props looks ugly. So I thought, this could work:

data.js

```
  export var data = [

                       {
                          "id": 1,
                          "title": "Title1"
                        },
                        {
                          "id": 2,
                          "title": "Title2"
                        }
       ]
```

and then just import it inside components I use the data in:

```
import * as data from './data.js';
```

...but it doesn't work.

Can't i have a little local "database" like this and import it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import * as data from './data.js';
```

means that every export becomes a property of `data`. So your `data` export would be accessible via `data.data`.

That seems inconvenient. You could either do

```
import {data} from './data.js';
```

Or change your module to use a *default* export

```
export default [...];
```

and use

```
import data from './data.js';
```

---

Have a look at the [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) documentation at MDN to learn more about how they work.